# How to print only the surname from a data frame column in ggplot2 (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose there's a data frame with all US presidents, a snippet of which is here:

```
    year winner           win_party  
    1860 Abraham Lincoln  Rep.       
    1864 Abraham Lincoln  Rep.
```

Using other code that isn't relevant here, I plot their names on a graph in `ggplot2`. However, I don't want the full name to be printed, just the surname (so e.g. Lincoln, not Abraham Lincoln). The problem is somewhere here:

```
library('ggplot2')
library('ggrepel')

geom_text_repel(
    aes(label = ifelse(winner %in% c("Joe Biden", "Donald Trump"), paste(winner, year), winner))
```

In this situation, "Joe Biden" and "Donald Trump" from the list of presidents would be pasted. Instead, I just want "Biden" and "Trump". Does anyone know where I can edit this for this to be possible?

Answer (score 1):

If we want to create a new column of substring, `word` can be used to extract the second word from 'winner' column and it can be passed as `label`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(last_name = word(winner, 2))
```